# How to get the data from the Eloquent joins in laravel?

Tags: laravel, join, eloquent, left-join

I am new to the laravel, i write Eloquent query for fetching the details from the both matching elements from two tables

```
Books Table
-----
id
name
created_by

OrdersTable
-----------
id
username
updated_at
```

There is a relation ship between `created_by` from Books table to Orderstable `id` , i want to fetch both matching records, can you please help me to achieve this thing

```
$v=Books::whereNotNull('created_by')->leftJoin('orders',function($join){
            $join->on('Books.created_by','=','Orders.id');
        })->get();
//created_by column some times null also so that's why i added NoNull condition
```

Comment: please read about eloquent relationship https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships .

Comment: Better add more details to the question. Provide the output format you are expecting with some sample data.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to read the documentation for Laravel Eloquent Relationships.

You can get your data in a single line instead of going around and doing the same work which laravel `Eloquent` can do in one line.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

You can figure out the relationship you want between two models and use it according to documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write their models after that you have to write elaquent function like this :

```
public function getBooks(){

return $this->hasMany('App\Models\yourOtherModelPath' , 'book_id' , 'id');

}
```

after this when you wrote query $OrdersTable->getBooks(); you have elequent